# The following error pops when I try to scrape web data : module 'html5lib.treebuilders' has no attribute '_base'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

I am trying out web scraping in python using beautiful soup, being a newbie took the source code from [[https://syntaxbytetutorials.com/beautifulsoup-4-python-web-scraping-to-csv-excel-file/]](http://%5Bhttps://syntaxbytetutorials.com/beautifulsoup-4-python-web-scraping-to-csv-excel-file/%5D) and started experimenting.
Now, I have an error

> module 'html5lib.treebuilders' has no attribute '_base'`

It would be really helpful someone explained me the reason behind the error and provide a solution for it
:)

```
import urllib.request as urllib
import csv
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 
rank_page = 'https://socialblade.com/youtube/top/50/mostviewed'
request = urllib.Request(rank_page, headers={'User-Agent':'Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36'})
page = urllib.urlopen(request)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
 
channels = soup.find('div', attrs={'style': 'float: right; width: 900px;'}).find_all('div', recursive=False)[4:]
 
file = open('topyoutubers.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(file)
 
# write title row
writer.writerow(['Username', 'Uploads', 'Views'])
 
for channel in channels:
    username = channel.find('div', attrs={'style': 'float: left; width: 350px; line-height: 25px;'}).a.text.strip()
    uploads = channel.find('div', attrs={'style': 'float: left; width: 80px;'}).span.text.strip()
    views = channel.find_all('div', attrs={'style': 'float: left; width: 150px;'})[1].span.text.strip()
 
    print (username + ' ' + uploads + ' ' + views)
    writer.writerow([username.encode('utf-8'), uploads.encode('utf-8'), views.encode('utf-8')])
 
file.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing the string "_base" by "base" in "_html5lib.py " .

Can you show the traceback of your error ? that which line or file the error is coming from .

Comment: Here man just attached the screen grab [link](https://imgur.com/5uZfp9m)

Comment: Try going to  _html5lib.py  by ~/bs4/builder/_html5lib.py and replace the string "_base" by "base"  work??

Comment: Apparently the feature is missing, I have replaced _base with base !!! [link](https://imgur.com/a/QxqyYok)

Comment: run  (pip install lxml) and then add "lxml" instead of 'html.parser'   work ?

Comment: did it work when you add it to line 9 soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

Comment: yeah seems like working but with a catch [link](https://imgur.com/JLa6OHS)

Comment: In line file = open('topyoutubers.csv', 'wb')  change it to file = open('topyoutubers.csv', 'w')

Comment: @Gowthamrk Thanks mate its working, overlooked that !!! thanks a lot !!!!!

Comment: @Gowtamrk you really helped me, but got to know stackoverflow has a weird policy to allow upvoting only after 15 reputations !!!! Its recorded but aren't shown publicly. Very thanks mate and keep up the good work helping novice like me :)  !!!!!